# Entity Framework and whole word matching - paging and filtering results

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

**Background**:

I am using ASP.NET MVC4, SQL Server 2008 R2, and Entity Framework 5 for a website.

The site accepts a delimited list of keywords to search database content on. It also needs to page the results to the user (currently 100 results per page).

This was going along smoothly until it was requested that the keyword searching is not done with partial matching, but whole word matching.

**The problem**

Performing the whole word match AFTER I already have the results back means that I might not have `query.Pagesize` of results to show - which messes up the UI paging. Of the 100 partial matches from SQL Server on the first page, 20 may end being removed with the whole word processing.

I currently am building my query using LINQ and doing a AND search on the keywords like so:

```
// Start with all the MyItems
var results = UnitOfWork.MyItemRepository.GetAll();

// Loop the keywords to AND them together
foreach(var keyword in query.Keywords)
{
    var keywordCopy = keyword;

    // Look for a hit on the keyword in the MyItem
    results = results.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(keywordCopy));
}
```

And later on getting the total number of results, paging, and executing the query:

```
var totalCount = results.Count();

// Page the results
results = results.Skip((query.Page - 1) * query.Pagesize).Take(query.Pagesize);
...
// Finalize the query and execute it
var list = results.ToList();
```

Because I need to do whole word matching and not partial, I am processing with a regex the keywords and removing non-matches from `list`.

```
var keywordsRegexPattern = "^" + string.Concat(query.Keywords.Select(keyword => string.Format(@"(?=.*\b{0}\b)", Regex.Escape(keyword))));

foreach(var item in list.ToList())
{
    var searchableData = some combined string of item data

    // See if the keywords are whole word matched in the combined content
    var isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(searchableData, keywordsRegexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);

    // If not a match, remove the item from the results
    if(!isMatch)
    {
        list.Remove(item);
    }
}

// Change list into custom list of paged items for the UI
var pagedResult = new PagedList<MyItem>(list, query.Page, query.Pagesize, totalCount);

return pagedResult;
```

**Question**

Does anyone know of a way to do whole word matching with EF and do result paging?

Ideas I've come up with but don't like:

1. Chunk the results. 100 results back, 20 partial keyword matches removed, go get another 20, repeat. This could result in doing multiple queries when getting all the data at once would have been faster. It also means it would be stealing potential results from the next page which would have to be tracked with some sort of offset.
2. Get ALL the rows back (no SQL paging), then process and page in C#. This seems bad to get all the results back every time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well I see two alternatives (I may miss something easier, but anyway)

Either you use `string.Contains(keyword)`, retrieve all the corresponding datas from db, then filter with exact matching and make paging on the enumerated result (so you probably get "not too much result" from db).

The other way :

```
foreach(var keyword in query.Keywords)
{
    //add space at start or end of keyword for contains
    var containsKeyword = string.Format(" {0} ", keyword);
    //add space at end only for startsWith
    var startsWithKeyword = string.Format("{0} ", keyword);
    //add space at start only for endsWith
    var endsWithKeyword = string.Format(" {0}", keyword);

    // Look for a hit on the keyword in the MyItem
    results = results.Where(x => x.Title.Contains(containsKeyword) || x.Title.StartsWith(startsWithKeyword) || x.Title.EndsWith(endsWithKeyword));
}
```

Comment: The 'other way' you have has issues since the content is HTML encoded. We were going to be having another searchable aggregate db column without the HTML because of other unrelated issues - so it is something to consider. Thank you for the idea.

Comment: @merekel well, if you've got to do this other column, just add a space at start and end, and you can go with string.Contains only, adding a space at start and end of keyword...

Comment: @MetalGeorge indeed... (for the 2nd solution)